# How to use \n in typescript

Tags: typescript

I created a ts class with a const inside:

```
export const message = "message part1.\nmessage part2";
```

I'm diplaying the message inside a dialog box(of primeng):

```
<p-dialog>
  {{confirmMessage}}
</p-dialog>
```

confirmMessage is declared as string and contains the const message

\n is not displaying string in a new line
what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with typescript.  What are you doing with this message? How are you trying to display it?

Comment: If you want a line break in your template, use `<br>`

Comment: Where are you printing this message, in debug console or in web browser?

Comment: message will be printed to a dialog box

Comment: @user6617577 In alert in web browser? If so, native `alert()` or JavaScript implemented dialog?

Comment: What's a "dialog box"? If you still haven't understood it, your question isn't clear at all. You need to show more code, to explain better what you're trying to do. When you say "dialog box" what do you mean? Into what html element are you trying to insert this message and how? Edit your question and add the code that does that.

Comment: `\n` are not line breaks in html, for that you'll beed to use `<br/>`, so it should be: `const message = "message part1.<br/>message part2";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For angular,  when you want show HTML,  you should set innerHtml to your element.